# Date support in d.ts for servicestack typescript client

Tags: typescript, servicestack

By default servicestack typescript file dtos.ts generated by webstorm plugin makes all date properties as string.

```
// @Required()
to: string;
```

in servicestack .cs file this property is DateTime.
Any ideas why it is so and what do I need to do so it converts it to Date as asp.net web api for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike other languages, there is no "deserialization step" in TypeScript, i.e. the TypeScript DTOs just defines the Type that's returned in the [raw JSON](http://www.json.org/) which as there's no `Date` type in JSON, the Date value is returned as a string which is what it's Type is when it's converted into a JS object using JavaScript's built-in `JSON.parse()` or `eval()`.

The default WCF Date that's returned in ServiceStack.Text can be converted with:

```
function todate (s) { 
    return new Date(parseFloat(/Date\(([^)]+)\)/.exec(s)[1])); 
};
```

Which if you're using the [servicestack-client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client) npm package can be resolved with:

```
import { todate } from "servicestack-client";
var date = todate(wcfDateString);
```

Or if using [ss-utils.js](http://docs.servicestack.net/ss-utils-js) that's built into ServiceStack:

```
var date = $.ss.todate(wcfDateString);
```

If you change ServiceStack.Text default serialization of Date to either use the ISO8601 date format:

```
JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601;
```

It can be parsed natively with:

```
new Date(dateString)
```

Likewise when configured to return:

```
JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.UnixTimeMs;
```

It can also be converted natively with:

```
new Date(unixTimeMs)
```