# DateTime property issue when using servicestack autoquery

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

Thanks Mythz for providing such an amazing and powerful framework. However, I encountered the DateTime property rendered like this "/Date(1543681261000-0000)/" instead of "2019-03-25T12:50:3000" by using servicestack autoquery. I couldn't find any relevant docs. Please help me.

```
{
"customer": [
    {
        "transaction_total": 0,
        "text": "0067 83228780",
        "transaction_time": 0,
        "action": 0,
        "point_collection_on_registration": false,
        "id": 71,
        "push_notification_id": "null",
        "name": "0067",
        "ic": "27668",
        "type": 0,
        "phone_no": "83228780",
        "point": 5132,
        "balance": 1621.3,
        "issue_date": "/Date(1543681261000-0000)/",
        "is_subscribed": true,
        "is_expiry": false,
        "lang_preferred": "cn",
        "is_delete": false
    }
],
"count_all": 120
```

}

Comment: Help you to do....what? Do you need to produce the above JSON document?

Comment: The datetime is rendered to "/Date(1543681261000-0000)/" instead of  "issue_date": "2018-12-02T00:21:01" when using servicestack autoquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ServiceStack by default uses WCF Dates for JSON, see this answer for [different ways to parse WCF Dates in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44268376/85785).

You can choose to change how dates are serialized in JSON for any JSON Response in ServiceStack by [customizing JSON Responses](https://docs.servicestack.net/customize-json-responses), e.g you can change the JSON returned by the [Auto Query](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery) Service with:

- `?jsconfig=DateHandler:ISO8601`
- `?jsconfig=DateHandler:ISO8601DateOnly`
- `?jsconfig=DateHandler:ISO8601DateTime`

Or use the short-hand alias notation:

- `?jsconfig=dh:iso8601`
- `?jsconfig=dh:iso8601do`
- `?jsconfig=dh:iso8601dt`

Alternatively you can tell ServiceStack to always use ISO8601 dates in JSON in your `AppHost.Configure()` with:

```
JsConfig.Init(new Config {
    DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601
});
```

Comment: Thank you @mythz for your highlights !

Comment: Noted. I will do it