# allow for deserializing dates as js Date object in JsonServiceClient

Tags: servicestack

definitely related to other questions asked (e.g. [Date support in d.ts for servicestack typescript client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259201/date-support-in-d-ts-for-servicestack-typescript-client)), but i think i ask more =)

first, i do grok that json doesn't pass true JS Date as the reason why ServiceStack codegens the C# DTO DateTime to string in TypeScript...

yet in other fetch client wrappers, similar to SS JsonServiceClient, i've had good experience using the second arg of [JSON.parse(json, reviver)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) to look for date pattern and deserialize to proper JS Date...

to cut to the chase, as proof of concept, i've monkeypatched "JsonServiceClient.prototype.createResponse = function (res, request)", like so...

```
...
    if (isJson) {
        // return res.json().then(function (o) {
        //     return o;
        // });
        return res.text().then(function (o) {
            return JSON.parse(o, 
                (_key, value) => (typeof value === 'string' && value.startsWith('/Date')) ? new Date(parseFloat(value.slice(6,-2))) : value
            );
        });
    }
...
```

fyi for others, it was very nice to already have TypeScriptGenerator hooks to influence the codegen how i want, e.g.

```
TypeScriptGenerator.PropertyTypeFilter = (gen, type, prop) =>
    (prop.Type == "DateTime" ? "Date" : gen.GetPropertyType(prop, out var isNullable));
```

for background, it becomes very elegant to provide proper dates to a robust React DataGrid (i happen to use Telerik/Progress "KendoRect" suite)... when real Dates are present, the grid's native behavior can filter and sort on these dates versus not as well with strings.

mythz,

could you consider providing a "hook" into JsonServiceClient so that we could provide a custom deserialization function like this? or possible alternatives?

thanks for everything you do!

FYI, i'm using the latest v5.9.3 stack of everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a `parseJson` hook on `JsonServiceClient` in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client/commit/b515ed880250e963d67045dcb0f7c174ef41c313) where you can customize how JSON is parsed in the `JsonServiceClient` with:

```
const client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
client.parseJson = res => res.text().then(s => JSON.parse(s,reviver));
```

This change is available from v1.0.34+ that's now on npm.